# No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, django, heroku

When i running ./manage.py from the virtualenv shows this error

> (ENV)vijay@vijay-Ideapad-Z570:~/nightybuild/heroku-landing$ ls
>   landingpage  main     manage.py     Procfile     Readme.md     requirements.txt    static     templates   
>   (ENV)vijay@vijay-Ideapad-Z570:~/nightybuild/heroku-landing$ ./manage.py 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "./manage.py", line 8, in 
>               from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>   ImportError: No module named django.core.management
>   (ENV)vijay@vijay-Ideapad-Z570:~/nightybuild/heroku-landing$

but without activating virtualenv ./manage.py gives fine .

here is pip freeze output

> (ENV)vijay@vijay-Ideapad-Z570:~/nightybuild/heroku-landing$ pip freeze
>   argparse==1.2.1
>   distribute==0.6.24
>   wsgiref==0.1.2
>   (ENV)vijay@vijay-Ideapad-Z570:~/nightybuild/heroku-landing$

but you know what my app up & running on heroku fine .. I just cant figure out why it`s not running in locally .. ?

Answer (score 2):

That's because Django is not installed in your virtual env.

```
pip install django
```